# Git clone without git on remote machine

Tags: git, version-control, ssh

Okay, pretty specific problem: I have a git repository on a remote machine and ssh access to that machine. BUT there's no git on the remote machine.

When I now try to checkout via `git clone user@host:/path/to/repo`, it fails with the error `bash: git-upload-pack: command not found` - not really surprising since git is not installed.

My question is this: Is there any way around git-upload-pack? I'm only using git as a normalized file storage/named blob db, so I don't want make the server setup more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Is installing Git on the server not an option? I wouldn’t argue it made things more complicated!

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding the setup, this should be no different than having a git folder on a file share.  Worst comes to worst, just copy the repository to your local machine and work with it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the git client is not all that complex to install.  There is no server processes or anything like that, just a bunch of executables.  I'm pretty sure you can install in in your own user-space too if you want to keep your server pristine.

That would be my first option.

otherwise you can try a simple copy.

If you need to move around the repository (clone it) you *should* be able to do that just by copying the folder structure as a whole to some other place, effectively making a clone !  Not entirely sure here since i'm ve been on a force git diet for a while now but if memory serves I have used this very same strategy a few times already without problems.

That said, try and get the git client, it will make every thing much more simple (well almost everything, have not yet found a way to auto-fill tax forms with it ... sigh).

hope this helps